# PHP Codeigniter - ShowPage - UserAgent

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm in the process of creating a mobile site and I'm starting the task of converting our current app. I'm looking at using CodeIgniter's built-in user-agent class but I want to know if the following is possible:

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');

if (!$this->agent->is_mobile()) {
  $this->_showPage("newquote/newquotemobile", 'Test Mobile Page', $viewData);
}
else {
  $this->_showPage("newquote/newquote", 'Test Page', $viewData);
}
```

Has anyone had any experience in using CodeIgniter's built in user-agent class?

Comment: Why don't you just try instead of asking here? Besides, the [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html) says it works that way. Do you have any reasons to doubt it?

Comment: you could open a bunch of browsers and see if it works.. and there are mobile emulators out there.

Answer (score 3):

That is pretty much exactly how you want to do it (determine if the user agent is mobile) but I do not see why you chose to negate the condition. I think it the "!" is in there by mistake.

That is how you use the user agent class provided with CI.
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html